# React child component removes parent state after callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, cloudinary

I have a form where one can upload an image using the Cloudinary image upload widget.

The widget is wrapped inside an ImageUpload component:

```js
<Form.Group controlId="image">
   <Form.Label>Cover Image:</Form.Label>
   <ImageUpload
      curUrl={form.image}
      imageUrl={(url) => {
      console.log("Adding image");

      setField("image", url);
      }}
   />
  <p
     className={`custom-error-message ${
     !!errors.imageErr ? "show" : "hide"
    }`}>
     {errors.imageErr}
   </p>
</Form.Group>
```

Notice the imageUrl callback function.

When the child component calls `imageUrl` with the uploaded URL, the state of the whole form gets deleted, except for the image URL itself.

I'm using `setField` to update the form state:

```js
const setField = (
  field: keyof IFormErrors,
  value: string | number | Date | boolean
) => {
  setForm({
    ...form,
    [field]: value,
  });
  // Check and see if errors exist, and remove them from the error object:
  if (!!errors[field])
    setErrors({
      ...errors,
      [field]: null,
```

I don't think the error is in the `setField` function because other input fields that use this function do not remove the form state.

I am wondering where the error can be.

I have no idea how this error originates as the child component should not be able to remove the parent's state with just a callback.

Can it be an error with the widget e.g., 3rd party?

Or am I missing a fundamental understanding of React state and the binding of parent-child components?

Comment: is `form` variable object of fields to value? can you include rest of component, and also the setErrors part bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a suggestion given the amount of info that you have provided, so might not be a solution to your problem, but should still help you to find the root cause nonetheless.

First of all, I do not see any major concern in your code.

If the `setForm` is a `React.useState`, you can check the value by doing

```
setForm((prevFormValue) => {
  console.log(prefFormValue)
  return {
    ...prevFormValue,
    [field]: value,
}
```

This is helpful because this will help make sure that the existing `form` value is still there by console logging it out. If not, you might have a bigger problem.

You'd also need to make sure both `setForm` and `setField` are in the same scope of the `ImageUpload` component so all values/functions are readily available to use.

If non of the above helps, more context to your code would be appreciated to do further debug.

Cheers.

Comment: This idd fixed the error. How come though? Using an anonymous function should only give the current state as a parameter. Why does it have side effect here?

Comment: That's great, I'm glad it helps! Tbh I can't really tell why this works at all due to the limited amount of context you have provided in the question, but generally speaking, this is a preferable way to update a state that uses its own value, so I guess I just accidentally hit the gold mine by following the best practice. For more info, watch https://youtu.be/FzI7faHqM0M?si=S_sG0ic2gUAz0XTj&t=241